# React select onChange is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9956/

I am returning a select element in the render function in my `react.js` code.

But whenever I change the `select` value, the function in the `onChange` is not getting triggered.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return <select id="data-type" onChange={changeDataType()}>
           <option selected="selected" value="user" data-type="enum">User</option>
           <option value="HQ center" data-type="text">HQ Center</option>
           <option value="business unit" data-type="boolean">Business Unit</option>
           <option value="note" data-type="date">Try on </option>
           <option value="con" data-type="number">Con</option>
      </select>
    }
});


React.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('container'));

 function changeDataType() {
    console.log("entered");
}
```

This function is getting triggered only once when the select is loaded and subsequently when I change the value, its not getting triggered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`onChange` takes a function.

You are passing it `changeDataType()`, which is running the function `changeDataType` function, and setting `onChange` to it's return value, which is null.

Try passing the actual function, instead of evaluating the function.

`<select id="data-type" onChange={changeDataType}>`

Comment: is anything async in that code? seems like defining `changeDataType` after setting it as an event listener is a bad idea. Probably should move that method into the Hello object (next to the render method) and use `this.changeDataType`.

Comment: Instead of using selected attribute of the option tag. You should use pass selected value into select's prop in order to manipulate value easier. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value

Answer (score 6):

Functions that trigger when a component changes should really be defined inside the component itself.

I recommend defining your function inside of your `Hello` component, and passing `this.changeDataType` to your `onChange` attribute, like so:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
changeDataType: function() {
    console.log('entered');
},
render: function() {
    return <select id="data-type" onChange={this.changeDataType}>
           <option selected="selected" value="user" data-type="enum">User</option>
           <option value="HQ center" data-type="text">HQ Center</option>
           <option value="business unit" data-type="boolean">Business Unit</option>
           <option value="note" data-type="date">Try on </option>
           <option value="con" data-type="number">Con</option>
      </select>
    }
});
```

Here is an updated JSFiddle that produces your expected behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9958/

Comment: The Fiddle is broken. Message:  `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#53:16'>53:16</a> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&lt;'"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select id="data-type" onChange={()=>changeDataType()}>
```

Comment: Why should you wrap function with another function? Also you don't pass argument with changed data information

Comment: For button it's works