# React select element onChange not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I am creating a `select` React component that can be used on many forms. For some reason, the `onChange` event is not being triggered.

Here is the element (omitted proptypes and default props):

```
var Select = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      value: null,
    }
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if (props.defaultValue) {
      this.setState({value: props.defaultValue})
    }
  },

  render() {
    var formClass = this.props.error ? "form-group has-error" : "form-group"
    var validationMsg = this.props.error ? <span className="help-block"><small>{this.props.error}</small></span> : null

    var labelClass = 'control-label col-md-' + this.props.labelWidth
    var inputWidth = 12 - this.props.labelWidth
    var widthClass = 'col-md-' + inputWidth

    return (
      <div className={formClass}>
        <label className={labelClass}>{this.props.label}</label>
        <div className={widthClass}>
          <div className="input-wrapper">
            <select ref="mySelect" className={this.props.className}
                    multiple={this.props.multiple}
                    value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this._onchange}>
              {
                this.props.options.map((option, index) => {
                  return <Option key={index} value={option.value} text={option.text} />
                })
              }
            </select>
          </div>
          {validationMsg}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  },

  getValue() {
    if (this.props.multiple) {
      var selected = [];
      for ( var i = 0; i < this.refs["mySelect"].selectedOptions.length; i++) {
        selected.push(this.refs["mySelect"].selectedOptions[i].value)
      }
      return selected
    }
    return this.state.value
  },

  _onchange(event) {
    console.log('hi')
    this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  }
})
```

I added `console.log` statement with a hard-coded string to the function and it never prints to the console.

Things I have tried:

`onchange={this._onchange}`

`onChange={this._onchange.bind(this)}`

`onChange={(evt) => this._onchange(evt)}`

`onChange={function(e) {console.log('test')}}`

In case it matters, here is the `Option` component:

```
var Option = React.createClass ({
  propTypes: {
    value: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  },

  render() {
    return (<option value={this.props.value}>{this.props.text}</option>)
  }
})
```

Questions I looked at:

[React select onChange is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716421/react-select-onchange-is-not-working)

[My onChange not working with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434381/my-onchange-not-working-with-react)

[OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

[React input onChange won't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115571/react-input-onchange-wont-fire)

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9958/ (it works here!)

[onChange callback not firing in React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457220/onchange-callback-not-firing-in-react-component)

Comment: component is rendering in ui properly with all the options ?

Comment: Yes it is (and here's to reach 15 chars)

Comment: i just removed the class names logic from render, check this fiddle your code is also working: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/3j6k63ok/

Comment: Works to me too on v15.5.4...

Comment: Do you use any CSS libraries what can overwrite select component view?

Comment: Thank you both. I looked at the CSS theme and it is hiding the `select` and creating buttons instead, so the select never got the events, I must avoid using that class.